# cannot get string length in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, alert

Over 1 hour on this.  This is javascript code inside my index.php file.

```
function dostuff()
{

   var thepath = document.location.search.substring(1);
   alert('the path is ' + thepath + " (that's the full path)");
   alert(thepath);

       // TRIED THESE ALL -- NONE OF THEM WORK.
   //var pathLen = String.length("thepath");
   //var pathLen = String.length(thepath);
   //var pathLen = thepath.length();
   var pathLen = String.length(document.location.search.substring(1));
   alert('pathLen is ' + pathLen);
}
```

The symptom: the first 2 alert boxes appear no problem and both show 'thepath' has a valid pathname in it, and it is the correct, expected path too.

But no matter what I try -- see the 4 different attempts, tried one at a time -- the final alert() box NEVER shows up.
Why is  alert('pathLen is ' + pathLen)  not showing up?

(The other thing is -- I'm using XDEBUG and xampp and Netbeans and the debugger will *not* let me put a breakpoint in this javascript code, so I can't even step into it to see what's happening, hence the use of the alert()'s in the code.  I know the XDEBUG debugger I'm using in Netbeans works -- I've been using it all night to debug PHP code in a different.PHP file.  When I set a breakpoint though in any Javascript code, a 'broken breakpoint' icon appears and I cannot find what that means in Netbeans documentation.)

Comment: What makes you think `String.length` works? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: @Felix -- I based it on a sample online that used String.length() to get the length of a string in Javascript -- are you saying that the javascript String.length() function does not work or does not exist?

Comment: It does not exist at all... where did you find that example?

Comment: No worries.... post whenever you want/can, there is no rush. In any case, www.w3schools.com is not a good reference. Use MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: +1 @Felix, thanks for that, w3schools has helped me out, I'm such an amateur any knowledgebase is good for me, but as I've gone along these past 2 weeks, more and more I've said 'not enough info' when looking for help in w3schools -- have now bookmarked your link, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never seen that syntax before. You might want to try:

```
var pathLen = thepath.length;
```

(You'd be best off debugging with Firebug)

Comment: thanks, I'm going to look into Firebug -- will it debug both php and javascript and if only javascript, I wonder if I can 'plug in' Firebug into my Netbeans IDE?

Comment: @wantTheBest: Firebug works only in Firefox (in the browser). There is an extension *FirePHP* with which you can also debug PHP.

Answer (score 4):

```
var pathLen = thepath.length;
```

Length is a property of the string, not a function, so no need for the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

The length is a property of your string rather than a method.
You should be able to access it via the following:

```
var pathLen = thepath.length;
```

When you say the alert box never shows up do you mean it never appears at all? If you're using FF you can open the error console from the Tools menu and clear it then refresh your page. It should highlight any JS errors you have in your code. That's the only reason I know of that the alert wouldn't show at all. (I don't think there is a class method for String.length() which is probably where the error is coming from.)

As for XDebug, as far as I know it's a PHP debugger only I don't think it can debug JS.

Comment: Thanks K, big help here on several fronts -- I didn't know xdebug only worked with php, thanks, that explains it.  I also didn't know about seeing javascript errors - I'm using firefox (latest version) and believe me I'm busting out the error console now that I know about it.  Thanks.

Comment: No problems. FF error console won't solve everything for you but it'll help with any language errors etc. There's a plugin for FF you can get which will allow you to limit the errors shown to JS only if you want (might be included as standard now). There are better tools for debugging JS - I don't use it much so I don't have one that I use regularly.

Answer (score 2):

```
pathLen.length
```

No `()`.  length is a property; if you add the (), it tries to use the value of the property as a function to call, resulting in an exception.

Comment: thanks.  Guys, you all helped me out here, I have to accept one but they're all good.  To be honest I take issue with this 'accept' and not just for this good reason.  I'll come back later and take care of it.  I have modified the code and can now successfully get the length -- thanks.